# "on address of"

Tags: word-meaning

"The judges of the superior courts shall hold office during good behavior, but shall be removable by the Governor General on address of the Senate and House of Commons".

What is the meaning of "on address of", I searched for the meaning of the phrase online with no applicable explanation for it.

Comment: Please give us the source and the context.

Answer (score 0):

The reference is to the acts in Canada that govern the country's supreme court. It means that the governor general of Canada can remove (dismiss / fire) a judge when requested to do so by the country' upper and lower houses of parliament.

Canadian legislation would specify the majorities (in both houses) necessary for the this to happen.

(My answer is based simply on my reading. Canadian respondents might be able to give you a more detailed answer.)

https://www.lawnow.org/good-behaviour-and-tenure-of-supreme-court-justices-in-canada-and-the-united-states/